# How get all images and videos from instagram in one album without api?

Tags: android, jsoup, instagram

I want to get a link to all the pictures and videos of an album on the Instagram. But the `jsoup` library will only link the photo or video first.

My Code:

```
String name ;
Document doc2=Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw7V2CugRBO/").get();
Elements links = doc2.select("meta[property=\"og:image\"]");
for (Element link : links) {
    name += link.attr("content");
}
```

I also tried the following code but did not get any results, but it replies on other sites:

```
String name ;
Document doc2=Jsoup.connect("https://www.instagram.com/p/Bw7V2CugRBO/").get();
Elements links = doc2.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element link : links) {
    name += link.attr("src");
}
```

Comment: The images are loaded via JavaScript. Jsoup only parses HTML. That's why you don't find any images.

Comment: I want the images link, not to show them.

Comment: The page contains nothing except the simple svg logo. Instagram is build with react, so everything is loaded via JavaScript.